# How do i log to server-side console with a create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

TLDR:
How do i make a create-react-app which has a button that logs "button pressed" to client-side console, and logs "client pressed the button" to the server's console?

Context:
As an exercise i decided to perform the simple task of having a button which when clicked on the client, logs to server console "task executed by client now." I quickly figured out that this is way, way beyond my understanding and that the fact that my app was built the create-react-app way, and i run it via "npm start" severely limits the control i have over what happens on the server side. I tried some pretty ugly hacks to get it to work, but i can't do it without losing some amount of functionality elsewhere in the app.

Comment: did you figure it out? I need to debug a proxy with create-react-app but console.log is not logging anything server-side

Comment: @raquelhortab, i never did. I ended up running a separate nodejs instance just for the purpose of capturing client actions, and it ended up being a very pleasant experience using socket.io library.